# What's the difference between stackexchange.com/sites traffic numbers and Area 51 traffic numbers?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, stackexchange.com, traffic

Looking at the Money SE traffic numbers in light of the discussion about domain names, I saw this large difference:

https://stackexchange.com/sites lists Money traffic at 434 visits per day.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money lists Money traffic at 1793 visits per day.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 6):

[stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) was just updated today to use a new formula for traffic.  Area 51 is still using the old formula, but will be updated soon to use the new formula.

New Formula: **Median # of Visits each day for the past 14 days** as recorded by Google Analytics

Old Formula: **Total # Question Views / Total # of Days** as recorded in the API

The old formula wasn't very good at all because (1) it only counts question views and (2) it's averaged for all time, so it doesn't reflect where the site is *now*.  So sites that have grown were showing lower numbers than they should, and sites that have shrunk were showing higher numbers than they actually have now.

**Update:** Area 51 is now using the new formula

Comment: Ah, this explains the overnight bump from 700-ish to 1900-ish a little while ago.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the mystery!  I was wondering too.

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://stackapps.com/questions/1678/will-the-new-traffic-measuring-formula-be-available-via-the-api-as-well)

Comment: FYI The money.se [main page](http://money.stackexchange.com/) shows 1566 visitors/day and [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money) shows 507.  I suspect it is the same old formula/new formula issue.

Comment: It appears to be a 14-day rolling _median_ rather than an arithmetic average (with the actual value shown calculated as the average of the two middle values), see the discussion here, http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/q/1468/61

Comment: @Alecos Updated to say Median instead of Average, thanks!