# Reporting site traffic

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange-2.0, traffic

(note: I've seen the related question on [area51 vs stackexchange.com/sites traffic reporting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66609/whats-the-difference-between-stackexchange-com-sites-traffic-numbers-and-area-51). This is a slightly different discrepancy).

For cstheory.stackexchange.com, the site stats listed on the home page currently list 3129 visitors/day (and this number has been relatively steady). I occasionally visit stackexchange.com/sites to look at the relative performance of the site, and there saw a listing 1.5k visits/day, which is about half the number listed on our home page. This lower number also matches area51 stats for our site.

I was wondering if the home page formula has not changed over like the s.e/sites formula has ? Because the two used to match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number on the home page is the sum of view counts for questions across the specified time period.

(The way we store view counts is *extremely* strict (by IP) and closer to what "visitors" actually means, so we chose to change the name from "views/day" to "visitors/day". It's not exactly the same, but the spirit of it is much closer to visitors than plain old views.)

The number on Area 51 and Stack Exchange comes directly from the Google Analytics API.

Comment: ...which of course means that the number on Area 51 and SE doesn't count those of us who block Google Analytics.

Comment: then there are lots of people who block GA :).