# Where can I find the number of monthly pageviews for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, traffic

Is there a reliable source for the latest number of page-views stackoverflow.com receives (not the Stack Exchange network, just that site)?

I need a source that I can cite on my research paper.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps the most accurate figure would be the one [reported by Stack exchange itself](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic).

For example, SO currently reports 5.5 million visits per day:

<sub>(Click for larger image)</sub>
[image: SO traffic stats]

So, that would be roughly `5.5 * 365.25 / 12`, or 167 million visits per month.  
***Caution:*** Stack Exchange reports "median" figures!?  Median can be misleading for stats like this, as opposed to the *mean* or *average*.

Also note that sites link Quantcast, Alexis, and even Google analytics are blocked by many user's Adblock and script-blocking extensions.  (The reported stats never agree with my server logs.)

See, also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166074/google-analytics-and-quantcast-seem-to-disagree-rather-wildly-on-traffic-numbers

**Update:** At last report (3 years ago), [Jeff said that SE's traffic stats come from the Google Analytics API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66896/148310).

Comment: Note, at some point recently SO removed Traffic as a sort option. I think they wanted to hide the fact the site is seeing reduced traffic lately as it could be embarrassing.

Answer (score 11):

You can find aggregate traffic statistics for all Stack Exchange sites on [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com).

Comment: This link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 2):

Here I introduce reliable statistics on quarterly # of pageviews per tag and question:

- https://medium.com/@hoffa/these-are-the-real-stack-overflow-trends-use-the-pageviews-c439903cd1a

Source: Taking the archives that Stack Overflow produces quarterly - and doing the math between quarters.

Comment: Impressive blog post.  Good work.

Comment: Much of the visual data (charts, etc.) in this blog post appear to be broken. Good reason to use embedded images, instead.