# How do you find how many questions have been asked on a given site?

Tags: support, questions

I’m subscribed to three sites and I want to join others. Before I do, however, I first want to know their activity level.

If I go to [Stack Exchange](https://www.stackexchange.com) and look at the *[All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)* section, it tells me the number of questions.

Is this the number of questions overall or just the questions in the past month?

**I would really like to know the activity per day, not for the last month, nor for all time.** For instance, if you go to tags, you can see how many questions have been asked in total, as well as the number of recent questions:

[image: Picture of tags]

Basically, I want to know how frequently people ask questions so I know whether to join the site or not.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic

Comment: @Ollie I think this merits its own question.

Comment: @Xnero the linked duplicate does focus on pageviews rather than questions asked...

Comment: Do you want to include deleted questions?

Comment: No @bobble just per day questions /activity

Comment: It can be a challenge to find the site and check each manually but Area 51 provides a slightly different value (see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66612/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66862/282094) than [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369958/282094) or [its duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180132/282094).

Comment: While an interesting excersise it is a 
 rather pointless metric on which to decide to join a given site or not. I'd argue that it should first be about your knowledge and interest on a specific topic and second the quality of the questions and answers provided on a site. Lastly there is no penalty in joining a site, and even not in deleting your profile on it later, so wether there are 2 or 2000 questions a day seems hardly relevant.

Comment: @Luuklag only reason why I phrased it that way is cause I don't want to waste my associate bonus on a site that doesn't have any activity. Imagine going to a site getting the 100 rep asking a question and a week later it's still unanswered. You just wasted time and rep I know every site isn't meta where you get feedback with a minimum time of like 30 mins but it would be nice to know if they are active

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two figures per site for the number of questions there: the *all-time* number (22 million, in case of Stack Overflow) and the number of questions *per day* (5.6k).

[image]

If you hover over the latter figure (which often reveals more information about *a lot of* things on Stack Exchange), you'll see what that means: it's the average over the last two weeks.

[image]

To get the number of questions in the last month, you could:

- [search for `is:q created:1m`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+created%3A1m&searchOn=1) - note that that means [the last full month](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching); you might want to use a specific date instead, to get the number for the last 30/31 days.
- use the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/)
- use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (except that it's always up-to-date until the last Sunday)

Note that search and the API won't return deleted questions, and SEDE only if you use the `PostsWithDeleted` table.