# Why wasn't this No Longer Needed flag automatically marked as helpful when the comment was deleted?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, community-user, comment-flags, deleted-comments

There's something strange going on with a comment under this question:
[How do you find how many questions have been asked on a given site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369958/295232)

Timeline (September 17th, 2021, UTC):

- **16:45:10**: created by @rene
- **19:38:06**: flagged as No Longer Needed by a user whose name I anonymized in the screenshot below
- **20:12:42**: deleted by the Community user, when the question was closed

This *should* mark the flag as helpful, but in this case it didn't; it's still pending. What's going on here; a race condition or some unforeseen consequence of recent code changes?

[image]

Something similar happened again today on a comment under [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372117/295232) (the flag is still pending in the moderator queue). That comment was also deleted by Community when the question was closed; it did not link to a potential duplicate, but it did contain a link to another comment on [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372118/295232) which was already deleted a few hours earlier.

Comment: The system understands my valuable comments should never be deleted.  Flags on my comments can't be helpful. I guess you all have to live with this. Sorry.

Comment: @rene the system has become self-aware like skynet, Glorfindel pull the plug fast!!